# Second Use of GrailsApplication Mock in Service Test Fails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

I'm unit testing a Grails service and using Mocks to mock out calls to the
GrailsApplication class. I have one test that succeeds but when I try
subsequent tests they fail. I am using demand to mock the isDomainClass
method. I have tried copying and pasting the code from the test that
succeeds to the test method that fails but the second time the same code
runs it fails saying that no more calls to isDomainClass are expected. I'm
suspecting some leakage between the methods but I can't see where it is.

Things I've tried already:

- Running the tests from the command line (I'm running the tests under  SpringSource Tool Suite version 2.7.0.201105292341-M2.)
- Moving the failing test to a different test class (the test that runs first succeeds)
- Changing the number range in the demands clause to 1..5 (second test still fails)

Here is the relevant portions of my test case:

```
package simulation

import grails.test.*
import org.joda.time.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication

class ObjectSerializationServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

       def objectSerializationService

   protected void setUp() {
       super.setUp()
               objectSerializationService = new ObjectSerializationService()
   }

   protected void tearDown() {
       super.tearDown()
               objectSerializationService = null
   }

       void testDomainObjectSerialization() {
               def otherControl = mockFor(GrailsApplication)
               otherControl.demand.isDomainClass(1..1) {true}
               otherControl.demand.getDomainClass(1..1) {className ->
                       assert className == "simulation.TestDomainClass"
                       TestDomainClass.class
               }
               objectSerializationService.grailsApplication = otherControl.createMock()

               def now = new DateTime()
               def testObject = new TestDomainClass([id:57, someOtherData:"Some Other
Data", theTime:now])
               def testInstances = [testObject]
               mockDomain(TestDomainClass, testInstances)

               def serialized = objectSerializationService.serializeObject(testObject)
               def deserialized =
objectSerializationService.deserializeObject(serialized)

               assert deserialized == testObject
               assert serialized.objectType == SerializedObject.ObjectType.DOMAIN

               otherControl.verify()
       }

   void testSerializableSerialization() {
               def otherControl = mockFor(GrailsApplication)
               otherControl.demand.isDomainClass(1..1) {true}
               otherControl.demand.getDomainClass(1..1) {className ->
                       assert className == "simulation.TestDomainClass"
                       TestDomainClass.class
               }
               objectSerializationService.grailsApplication = otherControl.createMock()

               def now = new DateTime()
               def testObject = new TestDomainClass([id:57, someOtherData:"Some Other
Data", theTime:now])
               def testInstances = [testObject]
               mockDomain(TestDomainClass, testInstances)

               def serialized = objectSerializationService.serializeObject(testObject)
               def deserialized =
objectSerializationService.deserializeObject(serialized)

               assert deserialized == testObject
               assert serialized.objectType == SerializedObject.ObjectType.DOMAIN

               otherControl.verify()
   }

}
```

And the output:

```
Testcase: testDomainObjectSerialization took 0.943 sec
Testcase: testSerializableSerialization took 0.072 sec
       FAILED
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No more calls to 'isDomainClass'
expected at this point. End of demands.
       at grails.test.MockClosureProxy.doBeforeCall(MockClosureProxy.java:66)
       at grails.test.AbstractClosureProxy.call(AbstractClosureProxy.java:74)
       at
simulation.ObjectSerializationService.serializeObject(ObjectSerializationService.groovy:20)
       at simulation.ObjectSerializationService$serializeObject.call(Unknown
Source)
       at
simulation.ObjectSerializationServiceTests.testSerializableSerialization(ObjectSerializationServiceTests.groovy:68)
```

Comment: What version of Grails are you running??

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error trying to use mockFor on jms Message interface in multiple test cases.

I got around it by creating a custom interface that extends from the interface that needs to be mocked.  You would use the custom interface to create the mock.

e.g.

```
private interface GrailsApplicationTest1 extends GrailsApplication(){}
testOne(){
    def control = mockFor(GrailsApplicationTest1)
    //...rest of code
}

private interface GrailsApplicationTest2 extends GrailsApplication(){}
testTwo(){
    def control = mockFor(GrailsApplicationTest2)
    //...rest of code
}
//add more private interfaces for additional test cases..
```

I'm not exactly sure why but I think the mockFor behaves differently between interfaces and non-interfaces.  But that's just a wild guess.